# Proper perl switch formatting in emacs

Tags: perl, emacs, indentation, switch-statement

**Edit:** After reading the responses, I believe the answer is "don't do this", hence I marked an appropriate response as the official answer.

Is there an easy way to get emacs to display perl switch statements like perldoc.perl.org's [switch page](http://perldoc.perl.org/Switch.html)?

Here's the formatting on perldoc.perl.org:

```
use Switch;

switch ($val) {
    case 1          { print "number 1" }
    case "a"        { print "string a" }
    case [1..10,42] { print "number in list" }
    case (\@array)  { print "number in list" }
    case /\w+/      { print "pattern" }
    case qr/\w+/    { print "pattern" }
    case (\%hash)   { print "entry in hash" }
    case (\&sub)    { print "arg to subroutine" }
    else            { print "previous case not true" }
}
```

Here's the formatting in `cperl-mode` after `M-x indent-region` is run on the snippet:

```
use Switch;

switch ($val) {
  case 1                { print "number 1" }
    case "a"    { print "string a" }
      case [1..10,42]   { print "number in list" }
        case (\@array)  { print "number in list" }
  case /\w+/    { print "pattern" }
        case qr/\w+/    { print "pattern" }
        case (\%hash)   { print "entry in hash" }
        case (\&sub)    { print "arg to subroutine" }
        else            { print "previous case not true" }
    }
```

I'm having an inexplicable urge to stick with if-elsif constructs...

ps. I think [this](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/Customizing-Indentation.html#Customizing-Indentation) describes the desired process, but it looks like it'd take a while to parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I cannot help you with emacs. However, I will recommend that you stick with

```
if ( condition ) {

}
elsif( other_condition ) {

}
else {

}
```

rather than use the dreaded `Switch.pm`. See [Nicholas Clark's message to perl5.porters](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2009/02/msg144389.html):

> Switch will be removed from the Perl core distribution in the next major release.

More discussion on [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=453292).

As Randal Schwartz points out in a comment below, starting with version 5.10 Perl has a powerful [replacement](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-statements) that does not depend on source filters:

```
use feature "switch";

given($_) {
   when (/^abc/) { $abc = 1; }
   when (/^def/) { $def = 1; }
   when (/^xyz/) { $xyz = 1; }
   default { $nothing = 1; }
}
```

Comment: Switch.pm is being removed because it has been made native as given/when.  So your comment about removing Switch is good, but you replace it with given/when, not with Perl4 constructs. :)

Comment: @Randal Fair enough. But I have had my share of headaches with `Switch.pm` in earlier versions and if one is not using 5.10, one is better off avoiding it, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!  I definitely didn't know about given/when or the issues with Switch.pm.  This also saves me a lot of potentially bad refactoring time/effort.

Comment: Worth noting that cperl-mode parses given/when constructs much better than the StackOverflow parser ;)

Comment: cperl-mode 6.2 formats given/when in the same way as switch/case, and doesn't highlight them as keywords either.  I guess that's on the todo list, then!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a dispatch table, as Mark Jason Dominus outlines in [Higher-Order Perl?](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/pdf/02DispatchTables.pdf)

Comment: No I haven't.  Thanks for the information.  I can definitely see the use of dispatch tables, but this is somewhat off-topic considering the question.

Answer (score 0):

If cperl isn't formatting it correctly, try out perltidy.

Here's a neat function to run perltidy within Emacs on the current region:

```
;; Slick functions to run perltidy in place
(defun perltidy-region ()
  "Run perltidy on the current region."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (shell-command-on-region (point) (mark) "perltidy -q" nil t)))
```